# DateType column metadata column in Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra

I am working with Cassandra database. I have created a below Column Family

```
create column family USER
with comparator = 'UTF8Type'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and column_metadata = [
                {column_name : account, validation_class : 'UTF8Type'}
                {column_name : lmd, validation_class : 'DateType'}

];
```

Now I am trying to insert into Cassandra database using `Pelops client`

```
mutator.writeColumns(column_family, String.valueOf(userId),
                        mutator.newColumnList(
                        mutator.newColumn("account", "hello"), 
                        mutator.newColumn("lmd", String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()))                  
                    ));
```

In my case, I created lmd as `DateType` in my column family so I am not sure how to add that `datetype` through code. Currently I am adding it as a String but I need to make sure it is compatible with `DateType`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: try with data type timestamp

Comment: @abhi, thanks for the suggestion but I was not able to understand. Can you provide some example by which I will be able to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have already created a column family using cli. Now try using these

```
SET USER['somekey']['account']='AC-46113';
SET USER['somekey']['lmd']=1365490146534;
LIST USER;
```

Now you have do the same thing using pelops

```
mutator.writeColumns(column_family, String.valueOf(userId),
                    mutator.newColumnList(
                    mutator.newColumn("account", "hello"), 
                    mutator.newColumn("lmd", Bytes.fromLong(System.currentTimeMillis()))                  
                ));
```

Comment: That thing I know. But through pelops client how should I add it as datetype for lmd? That thing is confusing me a little bit.